# convert univariate table to multivariate table in sas

Tags: sql, sas

I'm struggling with convert univariate table to multivariate table in sas. I would say the 'univariate table' I mean maybe still a multivariate table...but here's an example:

`a      b      c
1001   1      4      8
1001   2      3      7
1002   11     9      6
1002   5      14     15`

I want it to be like:

`a1      b1      c1      a2     b2     c3
1001  1       4       8       2      3      7
1002  11      9       6       5      14     15`

since I have thousands of ids(like 1001-3000). is there an simple way that I can flip the table around??

Many Thanks!

Comment: Are the number of records in each ID the same?  If not, do you know the max number ahead of time?

Comment: Proc transpose can do that. Here is a tutorial: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/ltow_transpose.htm

Comment: Thank you very much Jaamor! @.@ I was thinking could be an one step proc..

Answer (score 0):

Not a simple way because you're doing multiple values. 
You can do a transpose 3 times - once for each values and merge via the link from @jaamor.  Or you can do a semi-manual data step transpose. This assumes a max count of 2. If you have more than 2 per ID you can calculate the max and put it into a macro variable. Then replace the 2's in the code with the macro variable.

```
data want;
set have;
by id;

array _a(2) a1-a2;
array _b(2) b1-b2;
array _c(2) c1-c2;

retain a: b: c:;


if first.id then count=1;
else count+1;

_a(count)=a;
_b(count)=b;
_c(count)=c;

if last.id then output;

 drop a b c count;

run;
```